# Is there a good (non-calculational) reason for the formula $|v \times w|^2 + (v \cdot w)^2 = (|v||w|)^2$?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, exterior-algebra, cross-product

If $v$ and $w$ are 3D vectors, we have the formula $$|v \times w|^2 + (v \cdot w)^2 = (|v||w|)^2.$$ This formula is used to give the magnitude formula $|v \times w| = |v| |w| \sin(\theta)$. But the only explanation I have ever seen for it is calculational — write down both sides. It's very unsatisfying, in my view.

Is there a better reason for this formula than just "bash it out"? I would welcome both geometric answers or algebraic answers, but they shouldn't secretly use the above formula or the magnitude formula itself.

Comment: Divide both sides by $|w|^2$ and you get the geometric formula for "perpendicular projection + parallel projection equals the original vector". Since these components form a right triangle, this equation is in Pythagorean, instead of vectorial, form.

Comment: @NinadMunshi If you post this as an answer I'd accept it. That's great.

Comment: The homogeneity of your equation allows to assume $|v|=|w|=1$, so that it just says that $\sin^2\phi+\cos^\phi=1$ for the angle $\phi$ between the two vectors $v$ and $w$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter That's assuming you know the magnitude formula, which one doesn't from first principles. I normally use this fact to *derive* the magnitude formula. Ninad's answer is the more directly geometric one: $(v \times w)/|w|^2$ is the part of $v$ perpendicular to $w$.

Comment: I believe this should be derivable using the formalism of geometric algebra.

Comment: @JokeOoferOne way to define $\vec a\times \vec b$ and $\vec a\cdot \vec b$ is as follows:  $$\begin{align}\vec a\times \vec b&\equiv |\vec a|\,|\vec b|\,\sin(\theta)\hat n\\\\\vec a\cdot \vec b &\equiv  |\vec a|\,|\vec b|\,\cos(\theta)\end{align}$$where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors and $\hat n$ is a unit vector perpendicular to the plane spanned by the vectors and conforms to the right-hand rule.From those definitions, one can show that $\vec a\cdot \vec b=\sum_{i=1}^3a_ib_i$ and analogously for the cross product. See [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Definition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide the left side of the equation by $|w|^2$

$$\frac{|v\times w|^2}{|w|^2} + \frac{|v\cdot w|^2}{|w|^2}$$

$v$ crossed with the unit vector in the $w$ direction gives a vector perpendicular to both $v$ and $w$. Taking the cross product again with the unit vector gives us a vector in the same plane as $v$ and $w$, but still perpendicular to $w$ thus

$$\operatorname{Proj}_{w^\perp}v = \frac{w}{|w|} \times \left(v \times \frac{w}{|w|}\right)$$

Similarly, taking dot product gives us that

$$\operatorname{Proj}_{w}v = \frac{w}{|w|} \left(\frac{w}{|w|}\cdot v\right) $$

Since we have chosen a basis $w$ and $w^\perp$ for a vector that lives in a plane, $v$ can be retrieved entirely by vectorially summing these two orthogonal vectors. Thus by Pythogoras we have

$$\frac{|v\times w|^2}{|w|^2} + \frac{|v\cdot w|^2}{|w|^2} = |v|^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if we are equipped with the scalar and vector triple products, then we can simply write,

$$\begin{align}
|\vec a\times \vec b|^2&=(\vec a\times \vec b)\cdot (\vec a\times \vec b)\\\\
&=\vec a\cdot(\vec b\times(\vec a\times \vec b))\\\\
&=\vec a\cdot(|\vec b|^2 \vec a-(\vec b\cdot\vec a) \vec b))\\\\
&=|\vec a|^2|\vec b|^2-(\vec a\cdot \vec b)^2\\\\
\end{align}$$

from which we conclude the coveted result immediately.

---

If one is not equipped with the triple products, then we can proceed with a brute force, purely algebraic way to prove the identity.

We take as the definitions of the scalar and vector products of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ to be $\vec a\cdot \vec b=\sum_{i=1}^3 a_ib_i$ and $\vec a\times\vec b=\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3a_ib_j(\hat x_i\times \hat x_j)$, respectively.

Then, we have for the magnitude of the scalar product

$$\begin{align}
\left(\vec a\cdot \vec b\right)^2&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^3a_ib_i\right)^2\\\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^2a_ia_jb_ib_j\tag1
\end{align}$$

and we have for the magnitude of the vector product

$$\begin{align}
|\vec a\times \vec b|^2&=\left|\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3 a_ib_j(\hat x_i\times \hat x_j)\right|^2\\\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3 a_ib_j(\hat x_i\times \hat x_j)\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{k=1}^3\sum_{\ell=1}^3 a_kb_\ell(\hat x_k\times \hat x_\ell)\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3 \sum_{k=1}^3\sum_{\ell=1}^3 (a_ib_ja_kb_\ell)(\hat x_i\times \hat x_j)\cdot (\hat x_k\times \hat x_\ell)\\\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3 \sum_{k=1}^3\sum_{\ell=1}^3(a_ib_ja_kb_\ell)(\delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}-\delta_{jk}\delta_{i\ell})\\\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3(a_i^2b_j^2-a_ia_jb_ib_j)\\\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^3a_i^2\sum_{j=1}^3b_j^2-\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^2a_ia_jb_ib_j\tag2
\end{align}$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ reveals

$$|\vec a\times \vec b|^2+\left(\vec a\cdot \vec b\right)^2=|\vec a|^2|\vec b|^2$$

as was to be shown.

Comment: @jokeoofor Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

This identity arises naturally if you define dot product and cross product using quaternions. Given two vectors $v=(x,y,z)$ and $w=(x',y',z')$ in $\mathbb R^3$, their dot product and cross product can be defined as $-\Re(qq')$ and $\Im(qq')$, where $q$ and $q'$ are the purely imaginary quaternions $q=x\mathbf i+y\mathbf j+z\mathbf k$ and $q'=x'\mathbf i+y'\mathbf j+z'\mathbf k$. Therefore $(v\cdot w)^2+|v\times w|^2=|qq'|^2=|q|^2|q'|^2=|v|^2|w|^2$.